# python minor version in built wheel name

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-wheel, pyproject.toml

I am trying to include the minor python version in the name of a wheel built with `pip wheel`. My project is based on a `pyproject.toml` that specifies version number etc. and also requires a concrete minor version of python via `requires-python`.

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ['setuptools']
build-backend = 'setuptools.build_meta'

[project]
version = '1.0.0'
name = 'my-package'

requires-python = '==3.10.*'

dependencies = [
  ...
]
```

However, when building the wheel

```bash
pip wheel --no-deps .
```

the resulting file's name is `my_package-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl`.

What I would like however is `my_package-1.0.0-py310-none-any.whl`. How can I get pip to include the minor version? Is there some setting in `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: care to explain why this got voted down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually specify the python tag used in the generated wheel doing the following:

```ini
[tool.distutils.bdist_wheel]
python-tag = "py310"
# ...
```

An example for the usage of this is [black 19.10b0](https://pypi.org/project/black/19.10b0/#files) ([corresponding config](https://github.com/psf/black/blob/6bedb5c58a7d8c25aa9509f8217bc24e9797e90d/setup.cfg#L2)) (though they do it in their `setup.cfg`).

**Note that the now generated wheel is still compatible with higher python versions (in this case 3.11, 3.12 and 3.13 as well as every future version).**

You can read more about this in the [`wheel tags` docs](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/wheel_tags.html)

Comment: AH, I should've known to look in the docs for wheel :'-) thanks for the swift reply! Can I limit the wheel to 3.10? Or do I just push a 3.11 release to the pypi registry which then gets used instead for py>=3.11?

Comment: As of right now, I don't know any way to limit it over the python tag. However you could add `<3.11.0` to the `requires-python` and it would limit the package fully to 3.10. If you need a package for >=3.11, you would need to push a separate wheel to the registry.

Comment: right, yeah I have `requires-python = "==3.10.*"` there. It's just a shame you have to put this separately in two places in the toml.